# My MFC Application Freezes if I Switch to Another App

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

**Commence V 2.0 of this question.**

My VC++ MFC application compiles and runs just fine. That is, until I switch to another window. As soon as my program loses focus, it freezes; I cannot switch back to it and if I move a window that is in front of it, my app window displays white in the space that the other window was covering.

Since I first posted this question I have been able to pinpoint what portion of my program is causing this behavior, but I still don't know what lines of code are wrong or why.

The main dialog of my MFC application contains a CTabCtrl called m_MainTabControl. This main tab control holds onto two tabs labeled "Basic Design" and "Advanced Design", each of which are tied to their own dialogs. Both dialogs contain a CTabCtrl with several tabs. And thus my problem  is born.

When I first created this tab-within-tab structure, I was having problems with my program freezing up when I tried to switch between inner tabs. Needless to say I was puzzled by this, until I noticed that if I first clicked on a control on one of the inner tabs I could then switch tabs just fine. So without fully understanding what the problem was, I set the focus to the first inner tab of the first inner tab on program startup. Problem half solved. When I ran the program I could click around on the first set of inner tabs just fine; if I switched to the second outer tab and tried clicking around its inner tabs without first clicking on a dialog control, it would freeze again. So I made a Focus function to focus the currently selected inner tab of the currently selected outer tab and called that in my tab change event (the one that goes off when you click on another tab).

That is how I got to the point I was at when I first asked this question. I thought my program was working just fine, until I played around with it a bit more and noticed it wasn't playing nicely when I flipped back and forth between it and another window or program. More specifically, as soon as my program goes out of focus some process goes haywire and takes up an entire CPU's worth of processing.

And now, the reason I explained my little tab structure and focus problems in such great detail: after much experimentation, I found that if I commented out the second tab on my outer tab structure (i.e. the "Advanced Design" dialog and all of its little children tabs) the remaining bit of my program runs fine, and I can switch to another window and back without a fight. "Great," I thought, "that's only about 90% of my program that I just commented out to get this working. Let's try and pare it down further." I put the "Advanced Design" tabbed dialog back in, but commented out the tabbed dialogs created by the tab control within "Advanced Design" and everything still worked fine. One by one I put back the tabbed dialogs belonging to "Advanced Design"'s tab control and every time I reintroduced The Error regardless of what tab I uncommented. I should also point out that one of the first tabs I tried putting back in (alone, of course) was my "Margins" tab, which is a MarginDlg class that I ALSO USE UNDER MY "Basic Design" TAB WITHOUT TROUBLE. This leads me to believe that there is something specific I have to do when creating tabbed dialogs within tabbed dialogs that I am not doing, or am doing incorrectly, kind of like how I had to mess with focusing to make it work at first.

I would be EXTREMELY grateful for any light that can be shed on the situation. I am including what I think are relevant snippets of code; as always, let me know if more is needed.

variable declarations from main dialog's .h file:

```
//tab stuff
CTabCtrl m_MainTabControl;
vector<CDialog*> m_tabPages;
SimpDesDlg* simpDesDlg;
AdvDesDlg* advDesDlg;
```

When my application starts up, it creates my main dialog, and the OnInitDialog() is called:
(everything above the TODO: comment is default VS stuff dealing with the stupid about dialog)

```
BOOL CspAceDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();


    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    DrawResultsArea();
    DrawTabs();
    theApp.Calculate();
    Focus();
    //simpDesDlg->Focus();
    //DrawToolbar();

    return FALSE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

DrawTabs() is where I create the tabs for my outer tab control:

```
void CspAceDlg::DrawTabs()
{
    simpDesDlg = new SimpDesDlg;
    m_tabPages.push_back(simpDesDlg);
    advDesDlg = new AdvDesDlg;
    m_tabPages.push_back(advDesDlg);

    // create a tcItem to hold the name of each tab during creation
    // and then get inserted, and arrays holding the tab names and IDs of
    // the dialogs they refer to
    TC_ITEM tcItem;
    PSTR pszTabNames[] = {"Basic Design", "Advanced Design"};
    UINT pszTabItems[] = {IDD_SIMPLEDESIGNTAB, IDD_ADVANCEDDESIGNTAB};

    //every member of m_tabPages[] will become a tab
    for (int i = 0; i < int(m_tabPages.size()); i++)
    {
        //set up the tab name
        tcItem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
        tcItem.pszText = pszTabNames[i];
        tcItem.cchTextMax = int(strlen(pszTabNames[i]));
        //insert the new tab into the tab control and create the dialog window
        m_MainTabControl.InsertItem(i, &tcItem);
        m_tabPages[i]->Create(pszTabItems[i], &m_MainTabControl);
    }

    //redraw so that the dialogs don't appear in upper left corner and cover the tabs
    CRect tabRect, itemRect;
    int nX, nY, nXc, nYc;

    m_MainTabControl.GetClientRect(&tabRect);
    m_MainTabControl.GetItemRect(0, &itemRect);

    nX=itemRect.left;
    nY=itemRect.bottom+1;
    nXc=tabRect.right-itemRect.left-1;
    nYc=tabRect.bottom-nY-1;

    m_tabPages[0]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, nX, nY, nXc, nYc, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    for(int nCount=1; nCount < int(m_tabPages.size()); nCount++){
        m_tabPages[nCount]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, nX, nY, nXc, nYc, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    }
}
```

Main dialog's Focus() method:

```
void CspAceDlg::Focus()
{
    int curSel = m_MainTabControl.GetCurSel();
    m_tabPages[curSel]->SetFocus();

    //if it's the basic design, we need to focus its first tab
    if (curSel == 0)
    {
        simpDesDlg->Focus();
    }
    //if it's the advanced design, we need to focus its first tab
    else if (curSel == 1)
    {
        advDesDlg->Focus();
    }
}
```

code for m_MainTabControl's tab selection change event:

```
void CspAceDlg::OnTcnSelchangeBuildtabs(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int(m_tabPages.size()); i++)
    {
        m_tabPages[i]->ShowWindow(m_MainTabControl.GetCurSel() == i ? SW_SHOW :
                                                   SW_HIDE);
    }

    Focus();

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

SimpDesDlg and AdvDesDlg's tabs use identical code except for tab initialization (just creating different tabs for each) so here's the code for AdvDesDlg:

OnInitDialog():

```
BOOL AdvDesDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    DrawTabs();

    return false;
}
```

adding in the tabbed dialogs:

```
void AdvDesDlg::DrawTabs()
{
    //Make the dialogs for the tabs
    antennaDlg = new AntennaDlg;
    commSEDlg = new CommSEDlg;
    encryptorDlg = new EncryptorDlg;
    marginDlg = new MarginDlg;
    miscDlg = new MiscDlg;
    transRecDlg = new TransRecDlg;

    //add them all to the tabPages vector
    m_tabPages.push_back(antennaDlg);
    m_tabPages.push_back(commSEDlg);
    m_tabPages.push_back(encryptorDlg);
    m_tabPages.push_back(marginDlg);
    m_tabPages.push_back(miscDlg);
    m_tabPages.push_back(transRecDlg);

    //m_tabPages[0] = new AntennaDlg;
    //m_tabPages[1] = new CommSEDlg;
    //m_tabPages[2] = new EncryptorDlg;
    //m_tabPages[3] = new MarginDlg;
    //m_tabPages[4] = new MiscDlg;
    //m_tabPages[5] = new TransRecDlg;

    //antennaDlg = (AntennaDlg*) m_tabPages[0];
    //commSEDlg = (CommSEDlg*) m_tabPages[1];
    //encryptorDlg = (EncryptorDlg*) m_tabPages[2];
    //marginDlg = (MarginDlg*) m_tabPages[3];
    //miscDlg = (MiscDlg*) m_tabPages[4];
    //transRecDlg = (TransRecDlg*) m_tabPages[5];

    // create a tcItem to hold the name of each tab during creation
    // and then get inserted, and arrays holding the tab names and IDs of
    // the dialogs they refer to
    TC_ITEM tcItem;
    PSTR pszTabNames[] = {"Antenna", "Comm Support", "Encryptor", "Margins", "Misc", "Trasmitter/Receiver"};
    UINT pszTabItems[] = {IDD_ANTENNATAB, IDD_COMMSETAB, IDD_ENCRYPTORTAB, IDD_MARGINTAB, IDD_MISCTAB, IDD_TRANSRECTAB};

    //every member of m_tabPages[] will become a tab
    for (int i = 0; i < int(m_tabPages.size())/*(sizeof(m_tabPages)/sizeof(m_tabPages[0]))*/; i++)
    {
        //set up the tab name
        tcItem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
        tcItem.pszText = pszTabNames[i];
        tcItem.cchTextMax = int(strlen(pszTabNames[i]));
        //insert the new tab into the tab control and create the dialog window
        advTab.InsertItem(i, &tcItem);
        m_tabPages[i]->Create(pszTabItems[i], &advTab);
    }

    //redraw so that the dialogs don't appear in upper left corner and cover the tabs
    CRect tabRect, itemRect;
    int nX, nY, nXc, nYc;

    advTab.GetClientRect(&tabRect);
    advTab.GetItemRect(0, &itemRect);

    nX=itemRect.left;
    nY=itemRect.bottom+1;
    nXc=tabRect.right-itemRect.left-1;
    nYc=tabRect.bottom-nY-1;

    //m_tabPages[0]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, nX, nY, nXc, nYc, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    for(int nCount=/*1*/0; nCount < int(m_tabPages.size())/*(sizeof(m_tabPages)/sizeof(m_tabPages[0]))*/; nCount++){
        m_tabPages[nCount]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, nX, nY, nXc, nYc, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    }
}
```

And the Focus() and tab changing:

```
void AdvDesDlg::Focus()
{
    this->SetFocus();
    for (int i = 0; i < int(m_tabPages.size())/*(sizeof(m_tabPages)/sizeof(m_tabPages[0]))*/; i++)
    {
        m_tabPages[i]->ShowWindow(advTab.GetCurSel() == i ? SW_SHOW :
                                                   SW_HIDE);
    }

    int curSel = advTab.GetCurSel();
    m_tabPages[curSel]->SetFocus();
}

void AdvDesDlg::OnTcnSelchangeAdvDesign(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int(m_tabPages.size())/*(sizeof(m_tabPages)/sizeof(m_tabPages[0]))*/; i++)
    {
        m_tabPages[i]->ShowWindow(advTab.GetCurSel() == i ? SW_SHOW :
                                                   SW_HIDE);
    }

    int curSel = advTab.GetCurSel();
    m_tabPages[curSel]->SetFocus();

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: When you start your program, before you do anything, is it chewing up CPU?  It seems to me like you've got a run-away process that's preventing the messages from getting processed.

Between this call-stack, and your comment below (about focus in OnInitDialog), it's definitely an interaction between all the controls on your dialog.  If you don't know which ones could have hidden processing loops, start commenting them out until the behavior goes away.

I definitely get the situation you describe (no paint, no min), when I have processing in the main window loop which should be in a thread.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by 'processing in the main window loop which should be in a thread.' I'm going through college so there are still a few things I haven't learned about yet, and threading is one of them. How much do I need to know about this to understand how to thread a process which, in this case, I'm assuming is related to controls on my dialogs?

Sorry for the cluelessness here...

Comment: Also I just ran my program with the task manager open so I could watch my processes. When I first open the program it takes up about 5400K of memory and 00 CPU. And since I just clicked into my browser window to type in those numbers, the program went into its freeze state and jumped up 25 CPU (cycles?). I don't know what you consider chewing up CPU but I'm guessing the fact that it starts off taking up 0 means it's not initially chewing it up.

Comment: Finally, I will try commenting out controls. I guess I should just comment out a control at a time and then see if the program still freezes when I move to another window, but if I can isolate what control(s) are creating mayhem, do you have any suggestions as to what I should do to it/them to make it/them behave, or would you need to see code to say?

Comment: I'm actually totally baffled by your description (does nothing, them jumps for 25% when you click away).  Some control is going nuts.

Comment: After talking with some of my peers, they explained the CPU part to me. Apparently this computer has 4 CPUs and so the process suddenly taking up 25% means it's taking up an entire CPU--as much as it can get. Still don't know exactly what's going on, though; working on that now. One thing, though: when you said to comment out my controls, exactly what do I need to comment out? I was just going through each dialog and commenting out my message maps, thinking that this should prevent processing by the controls. Is that incorrect? Do I actually need to comment out the control in the...

Comment: DoDataExchange section of the dialog, and then proceed to comment out every single place the control is referred to in the code? I hope that's not the case; that would be really tedious. :(

Comment: Well, I just finished commenting out every MESSAGE MAP in my program (so all of my event-driven methods) and am still having problems, so I guess I'm going to comment out all of my controls and see if anything changes. If anyone still has the patience to try and solve this, you're a better man than I; I'm only still debugging this because I have no choice. :p

Answer (score 4):

Debug your app, get it into this state, then go Debug / Break All.  Find the main thread in the Threads window, then look at the call stack.  Somewhere in the call stack will be your code that's causing the hang.

Note that in order to get a sensible call stack you'll need to point Visual Studio at Microsoft's symbol servers; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx

Comment: Funny thing is that you cannot debug this situation. Once the breakpoint hits, the app loses focus and stalls. If you continue with debugging you (may) end in `CWnd::RunModalLoop()`

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe usually occurs when you are running some process without allowing the message pump to run.

What does your app do?  I assume you start it, and then either hit a button or select a menu item to start some process.

If the program behaves normally when you first start it (before you click to start your processing), but then behaves as you describe after starting the process, then that's your problem.

You'll have to move that processing into another thread to allow the MFC GUI to remain responsive.

Comment: When I run my app, I can click any of the control inside the app, run calculations, etc. and it is fine. As soon as I try to do something outside of my application, such as open a new Windows window or just switch to an existing Windows window, run another program, etc. then my application freezes.

Comment: If you start your app, can you minimize it *before* clicking on controls or menus?

Do you start any processing in the constructors or OnCreate overrides for the views or docs?

Comment: I cannot minimize my app (or bring up another app/window) before or after clicking on controls/menus. I don't override any OnCreate()s but I do use OnInitDialog()s to set up a lot of my controls' initial data.

Could be related: in the OnInitDialog() of my main dialog, I have a tab control that holds two tabs, each of which have their own tab controls within them. I was having problems with my application freezing when I tried to switch inner tabs before clicking on another control or outer tab first, until I figured out I needed to set focus to my default inner tabs. This required me to...

Comment: This required me to return FALSE on my main dialog's OnInitDialog() instead of TRUE (VisualStudio's default comments: // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control). I tried changing this back to return TRUE but it reintroduced the issue I was previously having and didn't fix my current issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled about a very similar situation. My setup:

- A `CPropertySheet` containing several `CPropertyPage`s
- A `CTabCtrl` inside one `CPropertyPage`
- Several `CDialog`s as part of the `CTabCtrl`
- Using a control in one specific `CDialog` and then switching to another application (e.g. Visual Studio via a hit breakpoint) will stall my application (the respective CPU core ends up at 100% load)
- Using a control in the same specific `CDialog` **but then switching to another `CPropertyPage`** before switching to another application will not result in any problems

After some research I found [this Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149501) which hinted me to a solution. The specific `CDialog` which triggered the stall had the line `EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` in its resource definition. Removing the line solved the problem.

This prevents being able to tab into the `CDialog`, but that problem is slightly less serious and I might come back to it another day.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had multiple nested windows, some with the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT style, some not. The thing is: Either **all inner windows** have to have this style, or none of them (at least apparently).